# Load the javascript file after loading the ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am using jQuery and Ajax.

**HOME.html**

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="javascript.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="div1"></div>
    <button>click</button>
</body>
</html>
```

**javascript.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('button').click(function(){
        alert('Button is clicked');
        $("#div1").load("test2.html");
    });

    $("#b2").click(function(){
        $("#div2").hide();
    });
});
```

**TEST2.html**

```
<body>
    <div id="div2">
        some content
        <input type="button" id="b2" value="hide" />
    </div>
</body>
<head><script src="javascript.js"></script></head>
```

When I click on button, Ajax loads the content in div. But when I again click on button then it is clicked twice. I know why this click twice happens, because I again load the **javascript.js** file.

If I can't do that then the hide button is not working because the JavaScript loads before the `div2`, that's why hide button is not working.

**SOLUTION:**

There is one solution is that I use the hide button code in `test2.html` instead of in `javascript.js` But I don't want to do that. 
Beacuse this is a demo in my original code this is very difficult to do that.
Is there another solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Repeatedly re-loading the JavaScript is a bad idea.

If you just want to handle clicks on buttons that are dynamically added, you can do that using event delegation. Remove `javascript.js` from `test2.html` entirely, and hook up your handlers like this (e.g., change `javascript.js` to the following):

```
$(document).on("click", "button", function(){
    alert('Button is clicked');
    $("#div1").load("test2.html");
});
$(document).on("click", "#b2", function(){
    $("#div2").hide();
});
```

That watches for the `click` event on the document, but only fires the associated handler if the event passed through an element in the bubbling phase that matches the selector in the second argument. When firing the handler, jQuery makes it look a lot like you had the handler actually attached to that element, rather than to `document`.

---

There's a lot more in `test2.html` than there should be. jQuery will only append the bit in the `body` (and run the script, but we're removing that). `test2.html` should just be:

```
<div id="div2">
 some content
<input type="button" id="b2" value="hide" />
</div>
```

---

Side note: If you're going to replace it on the next click, I'd use `$("#div1").empty()` rather than `$("#div2").hide()` so that you actually proactively *remove* the content you're going to replace later, rather than just hiding it.